# simple but not obvious identity in calculus

Tags: calculus

I'm having a little difficulty understanding this identity while studying for my calculus of variation exam.

\begin{equation}
y'\delta y' = -y''\delta y 
\end{equation}

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Its is obtained using integration by parts, with the assumption that your variation vanishes at the end points of integration.

Comment: Thanks but I still don't get it. Could you write it explicitly?

Comment: I wrote out the answer explicitly for you (at your request) and you never responded. If I answered your question sufficiently I would appreciate it if you would accept my answer.  If there is still some confusion let me know and I will revise the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These sorts of statements have to be considered within the context of integrals. In the calculus of variations the variation itself is usually taken to vanish at the end points of the integration.

Consider the following expression,

$$ \int_{a}^b y' \delta y' \ dt ,$$

we will perform integration by parts. Recall that the formula is $\int_a^b u \ dv = (uv)_a^b - \int_a^b v du$. We will choose $u=y'$ and $dv=\delta y'\ dt$.

$$ \int_{a}^b y' \delta y' \ dt = (y' \delta y)_a^b - \int_a^b y'' \delta y \ dt$$

since the variation vanishes at $t=a$ and $t=b$ the boundary term vanishes leaving us with,

$$ \int_{a}^b y' \delta y' \ dt = \int_a^b \Big( -y'' \delta y \Big) \ dt,$$

from this we can see that in the appropriate context $y'\delta y'$ is equivalent to  $-y'' \delta y$. As a short hand we say $y' \delta y' = -y'' \delta y$.

Comment: Terrence, was this answer sufficient?